# Related to HOME path

Tags: linux, path, localization, unix-timestamp, unix-socket

If I enter

```bash
$ echo $HOME 
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Why do I get this output? Why are `/usr/local/bin` and such in `$HOME`?

Comment: I don't understand (which part is unclear: what echo does, how variables work, ...?). `echo` outputs whatever comes after it. Variables (starting with `$`) will be expanded by your shell, before running echo. So the output will be whatever is the value of variable `HOME` and then the verbatim string you put after it (`/usr/local/...`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get that output is because that is the content of the `$HOME` variable. I think the better question to ask is "why is that the value of my `$HOME` variable?"

Typically the system will automatically set the `$HOME` variable based on the contents of `/etc/passwd` (or `sshd` in the case of an `ssh` connection, see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/271925/where-is-the-home-environment-variable-set) post). It is possible that you overwrote the value somewhere else, maybe in the `.bashrc` (or whichever `rc` file your shell uses). Those contents would seem appropriate for the `$PATH` variable but not for `$HOME` so I would start by checking your `.bashrc` (or again, whatever `rc` file is appropriate) and see if there is a line like `export $HOME=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` in there.